# Data pump exclude include

Tags: oracle, datapump

hello im learning about datapump and i trying to use include to filter which table i want to export.when i use the code below the import/export job able to run but  an error occur saying that the  table being skipped because the sql command not properly ended.how do i resolve this issue

```
expdp test/asdzxc@pdb22  directory=asdzxc SCHEMAS=TEST INCLUDE=TABLE:"LIKE'REG%'" query=regions:"region_name LIKE'Americas'" dumpfile=test12.dmp
```

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 5 23:17:06 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "TEST"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02":  test/********@pdb22 directory=asdzxc SCHEMAS=TEST INCLUDE=TABLE:LIKE'REG%' query=regions:region_name LIKE'Americas' dumpfile=test12.dmp
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
ORA-31693: Table data object "TEST"."REGIONS" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Master table "TEST"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" successfully loaded/unloaded

---

Dump file set for TEST.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02 is:
C:\USERS\MARCEL\DESKTOP\DPUMP\TEST12.DMP
Job "TEST"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" completed with 1 error(s) at Tue Oct 5 23:17:13 2021 elapsed 0 00:00:07

Comment: A space missing between "LIKE" and "'Americas'" ?

Comment: when i use space an error also occur   ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39071: Value for INCLUDE is badly formed.
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Where there's also a space missing? Didn't know one could use a "like" there, but then I quit before 18c.